# get specific data from webpage

Tags: php, android, web-services, webview

I have a button "Import Recipe" it will open the webview. User can search and select any site. The user can then press import button and then the recipe from that site will be imported to the app.

Each site layout is different and I don't know the div class name or any known format, so can't use jsoup. How to import just the recipe without the additional information.

Any idea how to implement.

Comment: You have to create a webservice in the website that will return the required data for the response.

Comment: how to get the specific data is my main concern each website has a different layout, no specific div class.

Comment: one way is to save the weburl on import button and save that in your app. Late you have access the url.

Comment: in each recipe site there is ingredient and method. How to extract just that ingredient and method div.

Comment: Save `xPath` from each site in your server --> get that xpath on url load via api --> user DomParser to get data